# SCAN and CSCAN algorithm in Operating system

Tags: operating-system, disk-partitioning

With

[image: SCAN]

and

[image: CSCAN]

I've gone through some notes and coursebook regarding the drawing of SCAN and CSCAN algorithm, given a queue of requests and the position of head starts in the example.

I wonder if it is a must to move from the starting position to the position zero first, then the head reverse its direction to another end (which is the non-zero side)...

Is it OK if I move from the starting point to the non-zero side first (if the starting point given is closer to the non-zero side eg.124). After that, the head reverse it's direction back to the side of position zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the given direction of disk arm movement.

You can choose either `Towards the beginning of the disk` or `Towards the end of the disk`.

There is a Github project about [**Disk Scheduling Program**](https://github.com/louisjuliendo/Disk-Scheduling-Program), take a look if you want to know more about it